# ASP.NET Web API code uses which pattern - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code in my so called repository layer.

```
public class EmployeeDetailsRepository : IEmployeeDetailsRepository
{
    private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public EmployeeDetailsRepository(IDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        Logger = LoggerUtil.GetLogger("Data access repository");
    }

    public EmployeeDetails GetEmployeeByFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;

        using (ILinqContext context = _dataAccess.CreateContext(""))
        {
            employeeDetails =
                (from stg in context.Table<Employees>() 
                 where (stg.Name == firstName)
                 select stg).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        
        return employeeDetails;
    }
}
```

What exactly does the above code mean? Every example I google is for ASP.NET Core. I know for the fact that this one is ASP.NET Framework 4.5 using Web API 2. But I see so many patterns while searching, what should I read/study to understand this pattern better?

I can paste more code if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is; it is implementing repository patter using [Entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)

When you call the above method, EF will generate a SQL query like below:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [e].[Id], [e].[DoB], [e].[FirstName], [e].[LastName]
FROM [Employees] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[FirstName] = N'Bill'
```

You can refer below for more information.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-Full-Stack/The-Full-Stack-Part-5-Implementing-the-repository-with-EF-Code-First-and-Dependency-Injection

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM

Comment: are there more youtube vids which use the asp.net web api?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

it explains well about this pattern

Comment: can you point to some youtube tutorials.